# Can JCombox share model but not selected item status?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

In my application I have 3 combo-boxes, each containing the same list of items, however each can have a different item selected. There is also a button that allows a new item to be added, when it is added it should be added to all three comboboxes, this newly added item  should also become the selected item for combox 3, but the items selected for combobox 1 and 2 should not change.

I'm trying to decide whether all three combo-boxes should share the same `DefaultComboBoxModel`. This would make it easy for the newly added item to appear in each combo, but unlike JList there is not a separate list selection model which would seem to scupper it.

However Javadocs for JComboBoxModel says:

> *The selected item may not necessarily be managed by the underlying
>   ListModel. This disjoint behavior allows for the temporary storage and
>   retrieval of a selected item in the model.*

So does that mean I can use a different mechanism for the selected item, I'm unclear on what the above sentence mean.

Comment: I wouldn't count on it. I think your best bet is to create three separate models from the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only methods that the `JComoboBoxModel` introduces is `getSelectedItem()` and `setSelectedItem(Object anItem)`, so I would say no.

Basically, you could place the data for each model into a single, shared list.  You could then create three new instances of a combo box model (either using your own implementation or seeding a `DefaultComboBoxModel`) that uses this data list.  These would then be applied to each combo box separately, so that each combo box had it's own model.

```
List sharedData = //... Create a list of data...
JComboBox box1 = new JComboBox(new MyComboBoxModel(list));
JComboBox box2 = new JComboBox(new MyComboBoxModel(list));
JComboBox box3 = new JComboBox(new MyComboBoxModel(list));
```

**MyComboBoxModel**

```
public class MyComboBoxModel extends AbstractListModel implements ComboBoxModel {

    private List data;
    private Object selectedItem;
    public MyComboBoxModel(List dat) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int index) {
        return data.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
        selectedItem = anItem;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        return selectedItem;
    }

}
```

You can just as easily use an array if that's what you've got

Comment: Thx, so if I have three separate models all inititiated with the same Vector and I want to then add a new item what mechanism do I use to add it, through one of the models, or directly add to the vector, or do I have to add item to each model

Comment: In order to add a new element, you need to have the model fire a notification that the model has been updated.  There are two ways you might be able to do this.  You could create a method on the model that allows you to trigger the protected [`AbstractListModel#fireIntervalAdded(Object source, int index0, int index1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) method.  This would allow you to add a value to your `Vector` but you would need to call the "update" method on each model individually for the views to update.

Comment: Alternatively, you could cheat a little.  You use a `ListModel` as your primary shared container (implementing something the `DefaultListModel`.  Each combo box would then attach a `ListDataListener` to this model (as you passed it in via the constructor` and simply pass on the update events, this would allow the combo box to act as a proxy

Comment: thx, but now thinking maybe easier to just keep the combos completely separate and simply call addElement on each combo in turn

Comment: Marked as correct anyway as you have provided a comprehensive answer